# How to implement custom delegate methods for my view controllers

Tags: iphone

In my app there are two tabbars. In tab-0 parent class is "FirstViewController" and in tab-1 parent class is "SecondViewController". In "SecondViewController" i have declared protocol and custom delegate method. i want to pass the information in "FirstViewController"(FVC). So FVC has to assigned as a delegate.

Now my doubt is, right now i am in "SVC". How can i assign "FVC" as a delegate of "SVC"?

In "SVC"

```
[[self delegate] sendCoordinates:self];
```

Definition of method is in "FVC". To execute this method, first i need to assign "FVC" as a delegate.

I hope I am clear in explaining my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate. Let me demonstrate:

```
`SVC.h`

@interface SVC
{
    id _delegate;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id)delegate; //sets the delegate
- (id)delegate; //gets the delegate

@end

@protocol SVCDelegate

- (void)sendCoordinates:(SVC *)svc;

@end
```

Then, in `SVC.m`, you call the delegate in exactly the same way as you showed in your question, so `[[self delegate] sendCoordinates:self];`

Now, in `FVC`, you'll need to `#import SVC.h` and initialise the object.

```
SVC*svcObject = [[SVC alloc] init];
[svcObject setDelegate:self]; //self now refers to FVC - I think you're missing this one
//work with the object and when you're done, get rid of it in dealloc:
[svcObject setDelegate:nil];
[svcObject release];
```

In the same class, implement `- (void)sendCoordinates:(SVC *)svc` and it will be called after you set the delegate.

I think you're missing the `setDelegate:` stage, which is why it doesn't work.

Hope it helps!

**Note:** In SVC, remember to retain the delegate, or it will become `nil` and no delegate methods will never be called. Don't forget to release that delegate once you're done.

Comment: Whatever you explained is perfectly fine. But here situation is somewhat tricky. To set the delegate i have to move to "FVC" than only i can set the delegate. And the program counter is right now in "SVC".

Comment: Right now Program counter(PC) is in "SVC". I want to pass the information in "FVC". For that i have to set "FVC" as a delegate. Code will work fine. But for that PC has to jump to "FVC". How will it happen?

Comment: In FVC, you'll need to do `[svc setDelegate:self]` and implement its delegate methods. Then it'll work.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But to run this code, PC has to jump to this code. And right now PC is in SVC. How will i jump to FVC ? I hope i sound clear.

Comment: I am sorry, but your terminology makes absolutely no sense to me. PC is in SVC? What? How can two different classes be inside of each other? This makes absolutely no sense, sorry I can't help you with this one.

Comment: FVC and SVC both are two diff classes When i click on tab-1, SVC will be loaded. SVC is gathering information from server, which i want to pass to FVC, which is loaded at click of tab-0. Right now, program counter is in SVC and gathering information.After that i want to pass this to FVC. But before passing it via method, FVC has to be set as delegate, Now the code you wrote is to be written in FVC, But what makes program counter to jump from SVC to FVC? I tried my best to explain this situation.

Comment: For SVC, it's exactly the same, just with the different class name. If you're using tabs, you can use `UITabController`'s delegate to set the delegate for the required classes.

Comment: I discussed this problem with colleague, and i came to conclusion that, I can not set "FVC" as a delegate, with Program counter running in "SVC". I have to jump to the "FVC", then only i can set the delegate. So your solution is perfect in this case. Thanks for help.